# Searching narrow down results React

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I am trying to explore searching and narrowing down to certain results. Problem is that search based on output from one filed is working ok but when i want to narrow down the results using second or third filed it is not working. I think issue is in here i do not know how to modify it to have this narrow results.

[image]

```
if (this.state.data !== null) {

  result = this.state.data.filter(state => {
    const regex = new RegExp(
      `^${this.state.name || this.state.email || this.state.body}`,
      "gi"
    );

    return (
      state.name.match(regex) ||
      state.email.match(regex) ||
      state.body.match(regex)
    );
  });
}
```

**Search**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
import axios from "axios";
export default class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          data: res.data
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  render() {
    let result;

    if (this.state.data !== null) {

      result = this.state.data.filter(state => {
        const regex = new RegExp(
          `^${this.state.name || this.state.email || this.state.body}`,
          "gi"
        );

        return (
          state.name.match(regex) ||
          state.email.match(regex) ||
          state.body.match(regex)
        );
      });
    }
    console.log(this.state.name);
    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.body);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <input
                  label="Name"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name "
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </th>
              <th>
                <input
                  label="Name"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email "
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </th>
              <th>
                <input
                  label="Name"
                  name="body"
                  placeholder="Body "
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {result !== undefined ? <Table data={result} /> : <p>Loading</p>}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Table.js**

import React, { Component } from "react";

```
export default class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <tbody>
        {data.map(el => (
          <tr key={el.id}>
            <td>{el.name}</td>
            <td>{el.email}</td>
            <td>{el.body}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to get *all* results where at least **one** of the entered "filters" matches? So if the records name prop matches `^el.*`, but the email prop doesn't match `^foo.*` or whatever, you still want it in the results?

Comment: what i want to have is:
I type for example "Maria" in email filter so getting results that matching maria in email cliumns and after tahr i want to have narrow down all "maria" with column body let's say "something". so i want to filter already filtered values

Comment: on screenshot i want to narrow down results fform filtering first collumn to emails with .com

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are okay with using `.startsWith()`, this would be a very clean and *readable* solution without Regular Expressions. They might not be necessary here:

```
result = this.state.data.filter(record => {
    return (
        record.name.starsWith(this.state.name) ||
        record.email.starsWith(this.state.email) ||
        record.body.starsWith(this.state.body)
    );
});
```

`.startsWith()` is [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility), but you can polyfill it as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill):

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
        value: function(search, pos) {
            pos = !pos || pos < 0 ? 0 : +pos;
            return this.substring(pos, pos + search.length) === search;
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want all the filters to match, just use `&&` instead of `||`. Also, if you want to find the string anywhere in the data (and not just at the beginning) the code could look like this:

```
result = this.state.data.filter(record => {
    return (
        record.name.indexOf(this.state.name) !== -1 &&
        record.email.indexOf(this.state.email) !== -1 &&
        record.body.indexOf(this.state.body) !== -1
    );
});
```

This still avoids RegEx, because it's not really necessary here.

Comment: thanks for taht but it is doing the same as my code so searchin all name,email,body for match i want to filter one column and based on taht narrow down by filtering on second ansd third collumn

Comment: @Damian i added another solution to meet your requirements (which i didn't quite understand before)

Comment: hey thanks, i think it is not what i need. i will try to describe. So when i filter column with maria and get 4 results i want to then search/narrow down those 4 results form email by filtering/seraching column name let's say with value 'el' and narrow dwon this 4 result from email by second column

Comment: But that's exactly what's happening, isn't it? If you filter twice, all the substrings you type in your column heads must match all the displayed records.

Comment: I prepared an example where you can exchange the filter strings in the code and see what happens: [https://jsfiddle.net/012kt4Lj/](https://jsfiddle.net/012kt4Lj/)